# I need to find the most suitable option!

Tags: sentence-construction

Which sentence is incorrect:

- a) The plot of the movie was too confusing. Nobody could make heads or tails of it.
- b) The economic situation is not good, so we have to do our best to make ends meet.
- c) You have to make do with what you have at the moment.
- d) We simply can't make without that. It is our cash cow.

Possible answer:
- a) 'make heads or tails of something' that seems ok

- b) 'make ends meet' it is also ok
- c) 'make do with something' ok
- d) 'can't make without that'. it seems to me that a pronoun is missing here. Wouldn't ' can't make it without that' be a better option?
- and so choice d) is the correct one.

Comment: You're right, but what the exercise probably has in mind is "We can't make **do** without that."

Comment: I was thinking on a) as another incorrect option: shouldn't it be *nobody was able to* (...) Since it was one occasion.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that **D** is the *correct* choice for the *incorrect* sentence.
Either **make do** or **make it** would be good ways to reformulate the sentence:

> We can't **make do** without it.
>   We can't **make it** without it.

the difference in meaning would be:

> We can't *survive* without it.
>   We can't *succeed* without it.

**Make do** would be thematic with the other examples you've given.